# PHP emoji to unicode not converting more than one emoji appropriately

Tags: php, function, unicode, emoji, bin2hex

This function converts emoji to unicode

```
function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
   $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
   $unicode = strtoupper(preg_replace("/^[0]+/","U+",bin2hex($emoji)));
   return $unicode;
}
```

usage

```
$var = ("");
echo  emoji_to_unicode($var);
```

So  it returns to me `U+1F600` the problem is if I add more emoji on `$var` it only returns the first emoji, example of return bellow:

```
$var = ("");
echo  emoji_to_unicode($var);
```

returns to me  `U+1F6000001F600` when it should return `U+1F600 U+1F600`

It works fine when convert a single emoji but not working when convert multiple emojis

Comment: It's what the function does: convert one emoji. It was clearly written with that intend. If you need a function for multiple emojis you should rewrite your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to iterate over each character in `$var`, converting it as you go. Note that to make the function more robust, you should only replace 3 leading zeros (so as not to mess up values that e.g. start with 4). That way the function will work with all characters. I've also added a check (using `mb_ord`) that the character needs conversion, so that it works with plain text too:

```
function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
    if (mb_ord($emoji) < 256) return $emoji;
    $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $unicode = strtoupper(preg_replace("/^[0]{3}/","U+",bin2hex($emoji)));
    return $unicode;
}


$var = ("xhello");
$out = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($var); $i++) {
    $out .= emoji_to_unicode(mb_substr($var, $i, 1));
}
echo "$out\n";
```

Output:

```
U+1F600xU+1F600hello
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bPcGC)

Comment: what If I have text with emoj too how to avoid text to be converted?

Comment: I got it, but text is also returning as hex I would like to keep the emoji but return the text as plain text string

Comment: I don't know, maybe something with `preg_replace_callback` or `mb_ord` would return the emoji in unicode and keep the text as plain text https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php, if you found a solution, please update.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto see my edit. That should do what you want. Sorry about the slow response, it's been nighttime here...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It's near machine level programing, we made the complex look so simple, thanks a lot.

Comment: How I would add the for inside the function so the function it self already  would run the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
function emoji_to_unicode($emoji) {
   $emoji = mb_convert_encoding($emoji, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
   $unicode = strtoupper(preg_replace("/0{3}1/"," U+1",bin2hex($emoji)));
  return $unicode;
}

$var = ("");
echo  emoji_to_unicode($var); // U+1F600 U+1F600

$var = ("");
echo  emoji_to_unicode($var); // U+1F600 U+1F600 U+1F600
```

Comment: what If I have text with emoj too how to avoid text to be converted?